# onmouseover javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

Look at this script:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#g{
display:none;
}
</style>
<a href=# onMOUSEOVER="document.getElementById('g').style.display='block'">
12</a><div id=g>hello world</div></html>
```

This is working but the

```
<div id=g>
```

is shown always when some one hover the link onetime. How to stop it so we can only see 
the content in div id 'g' if the link is hovered?

Comment: By the way, leaving out the quotes around the `g` and the end tags for `head` and `html` are 20th century constructs, meant to save a couple of bytes, that we don't need any more today. Not to mention both tags for `body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `onmouseout` on the div tag like this:

```
onmouseout="document.getElementById('g').style.display='none'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('g').style.display='block'"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('g').style.display='none'">
```

Also, wrap the id in quotation marks:

```
<div id='g'>
```